# How to assign dynamically value in @Meta comment in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to add a comment log in db.system.profile of mongodb, and it works in a constant variable, such as following.

```
@Query(value="{'field1':?0, 'field2': ?1}")
@Meta(comment="staticComment")
Mono<Quota> findByField1AndField2(String value1, String value2, Sort sort);
```

My question is if there's any way to assign comment in running time? or such as @Query to carry parameter in? I tried following, but it show up "{?2}" in comment of db.system.profile.

```
@Query(value="{'field1':?0, 'field2': ?1}")
@Meta(comment="{?2}")
Mono<Quota> findByField1AndField2(String value1, String value2, String dynamicalComment, Sort sort);
```

Comment: The point of doing this would be for what exactly? Queries need parameters but unless the annotation is being used for something which actually needs to be dynamically generated then there would not really be a point. I think you're actually talking about "adding another parameter" to the query since you seem to think this will be injected into the call. In which case it's actually another value in `@Query` and not somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Neil, my application will run in multiple separated server, and I want to know the query is came from which server, so I am going to add a server info into $comment.